# Почему маска SVG не работает с CSS clip-path?

Tags: html, css, svg

Я хочу создать маску svg над изображениями, мои коды ниже, но маска не работает, и я не знаю, что с ней не так. Фактический эффект, который я хочу сделать, заключается в том, что круговая маска находится над всеми `sections`, затем при прокрутке страницы вниз, изображения будут отображаться одно за другим внутри круга.

```
<div class="mask">
  <svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="circle-mask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>    
</div>
<div class="section"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593532847202-e818146e134a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" /></div>
<div class="section"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593532847202-e818146e134a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" /></div>
 ....

<style>
.mask {position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height: 100%;z-index:2;}
.section {width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
.section img {width: 100%; clip-path: url(#circle-mask);}
</style>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Why SVG mask doesn't work with CSS clip-path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62671376/7394871) от участника  [@BadJohnny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255460/badjohnny).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62671376/7394871

Answer (score 3):

При использовании `clipPathUnits = "objectBoundingBox"` вам необходимо учитывать значения в диапазоне [0,1], поэтому вам нужно исправить path  клипа, как показано ниже.

```css
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid;
}

.section img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  clip-path: url(#circle-mask);
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
  <svg width="0" height="0" >
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="circle-mask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.4"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="section"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" ></div>
<div class="section"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" style="width:auto;"></div>
```

Вы можете получить тот же эффект с помощью маски CSS:

```css
.section {
  height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid;
}

.section img {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fff 80%,transparent 81%);
          mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fff 80%,transparent 81%);
}
```

```html
<div class="section"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" ></div>
<div class="section"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" style="width:auto;"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672533/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>